# getSentenceInstance and whitespace

Tags: java, iterator

I am taking a text and breaking it sentences - creating an array with each item containing a complete sentence. I decided the best way to do this was using the BreakIterator class. Here is the code I am using:

```
theSentences = new ArrayList<String>();
String myText = aString; //the text is produced through a text box
BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance();
boundary.setText(myText);
int start = boundary.first();
for (int end = boundary.next();
         end != BreakIterator.DONE;
         start = end, end = boundary.next())
{
    String temp = myText.substring(start,end);
    theSentences.add(temp.trim());
}
```

This works absolutely fine when the user remembers to include a space at the end of a sentence (which most people do). However, people do make mistakes when typing, and if they fail to put a space after the full stop, the code does not seem to realise that the end of the sentence has been reached. What can I do about this?

I do realise that I could use regex instead, but it seems best to use BreakIterator as this is what it was made for. Also writing a regex that will distinguish between full stops and all the other possible uses of a period makes my head hurt :-)

Comment: The API doc says that `getSentenceInstance` works differently depending on locale.  Maybe you can find a locale that fits your language *and* recognizes full stops even without a trailing space.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for StringTokenizer? (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: (Specifically, using end-of-sentence characters as delimiters and enabling the returnDelims flag. (i.e. `new StringTokenizer(myText,".!?", true)`)

Comment: @Mike - two problems with StringTokenizer - first of all the use of ".?!" as delimiters means that abbreviations, numbers, temperatures, URLs and a whole pile of other uses of the period, will get broken up as supposed sentences.The other problem is that javadoc says"StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: Fair enough, but if your input strings include punctuation serving as something other than end-of-sentence you're going to have a hell of a time splitting up the sentences. It goes from 'splitting a string at certain characters' to 'processing human language and determining what constitutes a sentence'.

Comment: @us2012 - Thanks for the suggestion; unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any impact on recognizing a fullstop without trailing white space. I guess it mainly deals with things like recognizing the format of numbers or abbreviations.

Comment: Real sentence detection is some kind of machine learning task. Check the sentence detection documentation of Apache OpenNLP (http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html#tools.sentdetect.detection)

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut - Thanks for the comment. Again, this seems to be relying on the presence of whitespace. My problem is trying to identify a sentence when the user fails to include whitespace at the end of a sentence; this seems like a reasonable error to expect from time to time.

Comment: It relies on text level features, not on plain whitespaces. Just try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Very little.  Sentence splitting is not a 100% accomplishable task.  I myself use [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) and the ssplit annotator which is part of the pipeline to do my sentence splitting.  For simple tasks, this is a huge jar that you probably do not want to download, but it shows how complicated a task this is.

For a lightweight implementation of sentence splitting, it is best to implement a rule-based regular expression method.