# Get sentence from a String in Java

Tags: java, string, search

I have a string. Some of its content can be changed, and some of the content is fixed.

It is like:

```
String mycontent = "here is the sentence 1 . here is the sentence 2 . hereisthesomesentence3.here is the sentence 4. "

sentence 1 content : changeable  ,
sentence 2 content : fixed       ,
sentence 3 content : changeable  ,
sentence 4 content : changeable .
```

I want to take sentence 3 content, something like

```
String sentence3 = "hereisthesomesentence3"
```

Note: I do not know how many sentences there are since part of the string can be changed. I could end up with 10 or 20 sentences.

The contents of my string is like:

```
some paragraphs in here.// i do not know what is it writing .  After this changeable contents 
fixed content :"url" //  fixed content not change . But url can be change **i want to get url** 
some other paragraphs in here  // here some other contents.
```

Example code 3: (I want to get my url; we still have some parts changeable, some parts fixed)

```
Some Other Paragraphs
FIXED TEXT    

<span class="subcat2"><a href="myurl">
    <span style="display: inline-block; float: left; color: #ccc !important;"></span>  Hello World!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
</a></span>

Some Other Paragraphs
```

Comment: Just use `System.out.println("changeable")` since the content is "changeable"... *flies away* :D

Comment: so, how exact looks structure of this string?

Comment: What is your definition of *sentence* here? Do you mean each time there is a period, a new sentence starts? Will there ever be sentences like **"M. Smith took his shower in 35.7 seconds."** ?

Comment: This string , i do not what content is it .I just know there is somethings fixed and it is constant .I want to get content after constant words. There could be

Answer (score 1):

So every sentence is separated by a comma. Then you just have to split:

```
 public class HelloWorld{

   public static void main(String []args){
     String myContent ="here is the sentence 1 . here is the sentence 2 . hereisthesomesentence3.here is the sentence 4. ";

     String[] parts = myContent.split("\\.");
     System.out.println("Amount of parts = " + parts.length);
     System.out.println("Sentence 3 = " + parts[2].trim()); // trim() removes leading and trailing whitespaces
   }
 }
```

Comment: I think you need to split it based on a dot.

Comment: You can split by '.' and trim the results.

Comment: What about my sentence one **"M. Smith took his shower in 35.7 seconds."** ?

Comment: Thanks, got to get my eyes checkd :). A dot is more difficult as split does a regular expression and dot is a special regex character so beware of that.

Comment: considerring values posted under a string, it might be comas, not dots. Question is not precise, however if its dot, then you can split it by `string.split("[.]")`;

Comment: @T.G where did you see commas?

Comment: look below String definition in question.

Comment: This is useless. Because i do not know how much dot in there

Comment: So by what means does a string begin or end then? Magic is not possible.

Comment: @user3632921 - Please show some respect. The words *This is useless* are rude. Also remember, we are doing this for free, for you. Its not like we don't have other important things to do.

Comment: I do not want to be rude .But i just mean this is not what i search .Perhaps i could not explain it well .i am sorry for that .i am gonna add some example a little later .

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mycontent = "here is the sentence 1 . here is the sentence 2 . hereisthesomesentence3.here is the sentence 4. ";
    System.out.println(mycontent.split("\\.")[2].trim());
}

output : 
hereisthesomesentence3
```

Comment: i do not know how much dot in there

Comment: @user3632921 - What do you mean by that?. Can you show an example of what you are trying to say?

Comment: there could be 10 sentence in sentence 1 .Because it is changeable .So i should use sentence 2 .Because in there i know what is it writing and i just want to get sentence to after sentence 2 .

Comment: @user3632921 - show us the input you are talking about.

Comment: i add some new contents . i hope you will understand this time

Answer (score 0):

**code**

```
String mycontent =
    "here is the sentence 1 . here is the sentence 2 . here isthesomesentence3.here is the sentence 4. "
String[] totalSentance = mycontent.split("\\."); 
System.out.println("Sentence No. 3 = " + totalSentance[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this, adapted from [getSentenceInstance and whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182588/getsentenceinstance-and-whitespace)

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("some/path/to/sampleinput.txt"));

    ArrayList theSentences = new ArrayList<String>();
    String myText = String.valueOf(input); //the text is produced through a text box
    BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance();
    boundary.setText(myText);
    int start = boundary.first();
    for (int end = boundary.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = boundary.next())
    {
        String temp = myText.substring(start,end);
        theSentences.add(temp.trim());
    }
```